# using three while loops consecutively

Tags: php, while-loop

```
$connect = mysqli......
$command1 = mysqli....
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($command1)){
    echo $row[];

    $command2 = mysqli......
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($command2)){
    echo $row[''];

    }
}
```

this code line works properly.

- does first `while loop`
- does second `while loop` till it ends
- after second while ends, it returns to first `while condition`
- repeat all process until first while condition ends.

but when i add an another `while loop` all logic falls.

```
$connect = mysqli......
$command1 = mysqli....
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($command1)){
  echo $row[];

  $command2 = mysqli.....
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($command2)){
    echo $row[''];

    $command3 = mysqli......
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($command3)){
      echo $row[''];

    } 
  }
}
```

.... it press **first, second and thirds echos** to screen. then i am expecting it to return `$command2` again but it retuns to `$command1`, presses **echo** and stops.

why it returns to `first while` instead of `second while`?

what is the difference?

Comment: side note: have you looked into sql JOINs?

Comment: @VolkerK i am already using JOINs. but how these two are related?

Comment: @user3301042 Usually when you have nested query loops like that, it can be done in a single query by joining all the tables together.

Comment: You will probably need to show more code if you want to help us see the difference in each loop.

Comment: "how these two are related?" - It's just a side note. mysqli_query within a while(mysqli_fetch...) just lends itself to that question. But whether it applies here or not is virtually impossible to tell from the code snippet. ...it's just: likely ;-)

Comment: Oh and btw: How's your error handling? Do you at the very least check the return value of each and every call to mysqli_query() and if it's false inspect and/or print the error code/message?

Comment: whats the count of record set in each command?

Comment: @Trix .......  1-3-1

Comment: @ParrisVarney which parts i should show?

Comment: Maybe show the SQL commands?

Comment: Why not a (maybe) simplified yet complete version of the script. The current, crippled version has 13 lines of code. How many lines more could a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) have? Another 13? And mabye 15,20 more for the table definition and sample data as `CREATE TABLE ...` and `INSERT INTO ...` statements? That still fits nicely into the question text and makes it _so_ much easier for all of us.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

That's better you change your code like this:

```
$connect = mysqli...
$command1 = mysqli...
$command2 = mysqli...
$command3 = mysqli...
while( $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array( $command1 ) ){
  while( $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array( $command2 ) ){
    while( $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array( $command3 ) ){
    }
  }
}
```

I believe that would solve the problem

Comment: Precisely, very succint

Comment: While I agree that this is better, it would only cause a problem if the original code use `$row` in an outer loop after the end of the inner loop.

Comment: And I don't see how this would cause any of the loops to end prematurely. That only depends on what `mysqli_fetch_array` returns, not the name of the variable. This type of variable conflict is more of a problem in `for()` loops than `while()`.

Comment: @Trix how this will effect the code? its same thing.

Comment: In ur code, you are running sql queries in 3 nested loops. whats the reason for calling database like a forgetful man multiple times?!

Comment: @Trix but i am calling three differrent tables

Comment: Why do u insist on keeping them within the loops? move them out of loops like in my answer and see if problem exists :)